# Sitecore for Java Applications

Tags: cms, java

Can SiteCore be used as CMS for Java based applications? We have a suite of apps that must serve both video and image content. Is SiteCore an apt CMS for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore seems to be built on .NET platform, so depending on how you want to integrate it, you might need to create some custom portlets that use remote APIs. You could build a app (with .NET or Java) that uses Sitecore apis to synchronize content. I'm not very smart in this area, but you can use SiteCore as CMS for Java based apps.

Comment: Thanks Josip, I'm trying to see if they expose any rest api for saving and retrieving content.